# How to make msgbox to show the number of worksheets at the end?

Tags: excel, vba

Need this for excel vba project. Basically, I have created many worksheets with macro and At the end of the execution the macro should tell how many worksheets where created.

Comment: Add a counter and increment it by one everytime your add a worksheet. Then use `msgbox` to tell you what it is. If you need a more detailed answer, we'd need to see your code

Comment: If you're asking how to improve your existing code, then posting that code is always a good step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountAddedSheets()

    Dim vInitialCount As Long
    Dim vWorkbook As Workbook

    Set vWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Remember the initial number of sheets
    vInitialCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Your code to add worksheets ... for example ...
    vWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Show the number of worksheets added
    MsgBox "Number of worksheets added: " & (vWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - vInitialCount)

End Sub
```